# Material Design round mask in HTML, CSS & JS - how to achieve this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design

I want to set a round mask to a html element and animate it's scale.
Basically this is how it should look

[image]

The blue circle shows the content that should be displayed during the transition and the grey elements should be hidden at the time.

So far I tried clip-path and a square wrapper div with border-radius 50% and it doesn't give the desired result.

I also tried to overlay a square div with border-radius 50% and set the transition to it's box-shadow inset from original value to 0 but this works only if the overlayed div background has the same background color with the page (it looks bad if there are other elements/images behind the hidden elements)

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you consider a positioned pseudo-element and an outset box-shadow - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/MKxjBX

Comment: @Paulie_D I need something wich doesn't add a background. More like this one http://codepen.io/sorinbotirla/pen/QyoYgx but unfortunately clip-path only works on chrome

Comment: Do you want to be able to partially see the 'clipped' content (the light grey in your example? Or completely hide it (only show the blue)?

Comment: Please include the code you have so far in the question itself.